# Map function to the list and keep the previous

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

Give the following list,

```
list = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}};
```

I want to get

```
{F[{a1}]}
{F[{a1,a2}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}],F[{b1}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}],F[{b1,b2}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}],F[{b1,b2,b3}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}],F[{b1,b2,b3,b4}]}
{F[{a1,a2,a3}],F[{b1,b2,b3,b4}],F[{c1}]}
......
```

I have tried this, It is difficult to further promote, do you have a better way?

```
L1 = Rest@FoldList[Append, {}, #] & /@ list
L2 = MapAt[F, L1, Join @@ MapIndexed[#2 &, L1, {2}]]
Join[List /@ L2[[1]], {L2[[1, -1]], #} & /@ L2[[2]]] // Column
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define:

```
idx = Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 &, list, {-1}], 1];
```

Then:

```
    Function[grp, Values[GroupBy[grp, First, f @@ {Extract[list, #]} &]]] /@ 
       Map[idx[[1 ;; #]] &, Range[1, Length[idx]]] // Column
(* 
    {
 {{f[{a1}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], f[{c1}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], f[{c1, c2}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], f[{c1, c2, c3}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], f[{c1, c2, c3, c4}]}},
 {{f[{a1, a2, a3}], f[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], f[{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}]}}
}
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach. If we flattened your input list and used FoldList, we'd get something resembling the desired output but missing the list structure. But we could recover the list structure afterward by grouping according to the length of each sublist in the original list. Let's put this idea into a function:

```
FoldOver[lists : {___List}] :=
  With[
    {lengths = Length /@ lists},
    Map[
      F,
      DeleteCases[
        TakeList[#, UpTo /@ lengths] & /@ FoldList[Append, {}, Flatten[lists, 1]],
        {},
        Infinity],
      {-2}]]
```

Applying this:

```
FoldOver[list]
```

gives `{F[{}], {F[{a1}]}, ... , {F[{a1, a2, a3}], F[{b1, b2, b3, b4}], F[{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}]}}`

You can add something to remove the first element if you like.

This is a bit dense, so a suggestion for understanding it is to unroll it and roll it back up incrementally. So, start with this definition:

```
FoldOver[lists : {___List}] :=
  With[
    {lengths = Length /@ lists},
    FoldList[Append, {}, Flatten[lists, 1]]]
```

Which gives:

```
FoldOver[list]
```

`{{}, {a1}, ... , {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4}, {a1,  a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}}`

And then:

```
FoldOver[lists : {___List}] :=
  With[
    {lengths = Length /@ lists},
    TakeList[#, UpTo /@ lengths] & /@ FoldList[Append, {}, Flatten[lists, 1]]]
```

And then:

```
FoldOver[lists : {___List}] :=
  With[
    {lengths = Length /@ lists},
    DeleteCases[
      TakeList[#, UpTo /@ lengths] & /@ FoldList[Append, {}, Flatten[lists, 1]],
      {},
      Infinity]]
```

Etcetera...

Comment: (+1) Add `Rest@With...` :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}};
dlist = ReplaceList[Flatten@list, {x__, y__} :> {x}]
```

> {{a1}, {a1, a2}, {a1, a2, a3}, {a1, a2, a3, b1}, {a1, a2, a3, b1,
> b2}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4}, {a1,
> a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1,    c2},
> {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2,    b3,
> b4, c1, c2, c3, c4}}

Now these need to be partitioned according to the original sublist lengths:

```
(res2 = Map[F, 
    TakeList[#, UpTo /@ (Length /@ list)] & /@ dlist /. {} -> 
      Nothing, {2}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A little variant of Syed's answer is to get the partition of the list using
`Partition` and `Table`:

```
slist = Table[First@Partition[Flatten@list, i], {i, 1, Length[Flatten@list]}]
(*{{a1}, {a1, a2}, {a1, a2, a3}, {a1, a2, a3, b1}, {a1, a2, a3, b1,   b2}, 
  {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1}, 
  {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3}, 
  {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4}, 
  {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}}*)
```

Then, using Syed's code:

```
(res2 = Map[F, 
TakeList[#, UpTo /@ (Length /@ list)] & /@ dlist /. {} -> 
  Nothing, {2}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code below produces the required output when applied on input `list`:

```
ClearAll[flat,wrap]
SetAttributes[flat,{Flat}]
flat/:wrap[flat[args__]]:=F[{args}]
list//Map[(Through[{First/*flat,Rest}[#]]&)/*Apply[FoldList[flat]]]/*Apply[Join]/*wrap/*Thread/*List/*Transpose/*FoldList[Join]
```

In what's following, I will provide an informal walkthrough of the code.

First thing's first, attribute `Flat` on a symbol: [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) instructs the evaluator to replace nested expressions with a flattened version of the expression, eg:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, Flat]
f[1, f[2, 3], f[f[4], 5]]
```

evaluates to `f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Next, we'll talk about the [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) part. Using it on every sublist of the original `list`, it prepares the input for the following expression.

Its effect is to split a list into its head and the rest of its body; it also wraps the head with `flat`, which is a symbol with attribute `Flat`:

```
{a1, a2, a3} // Through[{First/*flat, Rest}[#]]&
```

evaluates to `{flat[a1], {a2, a3}}`.

The following step, involves [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html). To illustrate how it works, we'll present first a general case and then we'll specify how it helps to achieve the required output.

A plain use of `FoldList` like this:

```
FoldList[g, g[a1], {a2, a3}]
```

evaluates to `{g[a1], g[g[a1], a2], g[g[g[a1], a2], a3]}`.

Now, consider how this output would change, if symbol `g` were actually equipped with the `Flat` attribute. The answer is simply `{g[a1], g[a1, a2], g[a1, a2, a3]}`.

So far, we've actually produced a list with entries wrapped with a `Flat` symbol. In our original code, this list is produced after we `Map` over the sublists of `list`.

The next code snippet is

```
Apply[Join]/*wrap/*Thread
```

This simply joins together the respective sublists and wraps each entry with an auxiliary symbol (`wrap`).

Associated with `wrap` is a rule that transforms the arguments of *its* argument into the arguments of the designated function `F`.

Finally, `List/*Transpose/*FoldList[Join]` produces the desired output. The part `List/*Transpose` prepares the input for the operator form `FoldList[Join]`, which eventually evaluates to the desired output.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a basic `Table` with two levels which used `Catenate` to unpack and `Extract` (the third argument is used to apply your function).

```
ClearAll[fn];

fn[f_, data_] := Block[{lengths = Length /@ data},
 Catenate @ Table[Extract[list
    , If[listIndex > 1 (* start including previous items *)
      , Table[{i, ;;}, {i, listIndex - 1}]
      , {}]
     ~Join~
     {{listIndex, ;; itemIndex}}
    , f]
   
   , {listIndex, Length @ lengths}
   , {itemIndex, lengths[[listIndex]]}]
 ]
```

Also, you can use it with any number of sub-list.